# Why UDP maximum segment size is far greater than TCP maximum segment size in this output?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I tried the following code to find out maximum segment size in TCP and UDP sockets. I might be wrong because I am using `IPPROTO_TCP` and `TCP_MAXSEG` for `SOCK_DGRAM` but I'm getting a value and I want to know the reason.

```
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    perror("cant create socket");

aopt = sizeof(optval);
getsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, (char *)&optval, &aopt);
printf("tcp max segment size is=%d\n", optval);
```

output:

```
tcp max segment size is=536
```

then I tried then same with an UDP socket:

```
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    perror("cant create socket");

aopt = sizeof(optval);
getsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, (char *)&optval, &aopt);
printf("udp max segment size is=%d\n", optval);
```

output:

```
udp max segment size is=134514139
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure `getsockopt` actually fails (and returns a non-zero status you are ignoring) so you are printing garbage (it's likely you didn't initialize `optval`).

#### EDIT

`UDP` doesn't have a MSS. The maximum size of a datagram is limited by many factors (how wiling is the OS to send a big datagram). The hard limit is the size IP can carry. `IP` has 16b `Total Length` field. So I'm guessing if the OS lets you, `65535 - iphdr` is the maximum size of a datagram.

Comment: thanks a lot. it was garbage output. but how can i check for MSS of UDP?

Answer (score 3):

TCP has segments, UDP has datagrams. UDP datagram length is limited by the size of the UDP datagram length header field (it's 16 bits).

From wikipedia:

```
A field that specifies the length in bytes of the entire datagram: header and data.
The minimum length is 8 bytes since that's the length of the header.
The field size sets a theoretical limit of 65,535 bytes
(8 byte header + 65,527 bytes of data) for a UDP datagram.
The practical limit for the data length which is imposed by the underlying
IPv4 protocol is 65,507 bytes (65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP header).
```

check the return value of `getsockopt`, UDP doesn't have tcp segments so it should definitely return with an error.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as the 'maximum segment size of UDP', because UDP doesn't have segments or MSS. The maximum possible UDP datagram payload size is 65535-28=65507 as per yi_H's answer. In practice it is further limited by the NIC's MTU and by the intermediate routers, in exactly the same way that TCP's MSS is, however it is *not* negotiated across the length of the path like a TCP MSS is; it is therefore not known by the UDP stack; it is therefore not available to you via any API.

Comment: so UDP doesn't do any segmentation and just sends packet as it was provided by application layer? e.g. if application sends 2K packet and MTU is 1500, the packet is guarantied to be dropped?

Comment: @AndyT If the DF flag isn't set it will be fragmented, and if all the fragments arrive it will be reassembled, but there is no retry mechanism for missing fragments so the chances of losing it are increased. If DF is set it is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the UDP value that you got is because you're using *level* and options, which do not apply to UDP **BUT** to TCP. You need to use getsockopt as following

```
getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE, (char *)&optval, &aopt);
```

check [this Microsoft page about the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt)